# Facebook like notification or ajax calling?

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, spring, notifications

I have a google map, when a new coordinates inserted into database I want to change location of icon on map. Without ajax calling how can I implement this?

I am using Spring, Hibernate and SQL Server 2008.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Wait a minute, where does Facebook come into this?

Comment: I couldn't choose the exact title for this post :) I mean when a message comes notification icon changes. I want to implement this style of notification or ajax calling for my map. But I don't want to use ajax call every second or every minute etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use HTML5 you can use Server Sent Events.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_serversentevents.asp

If you are able to host on Goggle App Engine, check this out.  I believe it would support all browsers.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using ajax, you'd have to do a page refresh.  Don't know of a way to communicate to the server other than using ajax and doing a page refresh.