# is it Possible to use SignalR in .net framework 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have an Existing website that was built in .net 2.0. is it possible to integrate the signalr on it? if Yes please let me know how..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible even SignalR version 1.0 needs .net framework 4.5, 
see here [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-1x/getting-started-with-aspnet-signalr/supported-platforms)

Comment: Okay.. thanks.. is there any possible solution that i can use to have my own facebook like notification.?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's not possible! you can't even use signalR in .Net4.
see [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1723) for more information

Comment: Okay.. thanks.. is there any possible solution that i can use to have my own facebook like notification.?

Comment: you can use ajax call or html5 to do that.see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488109/facebook-like-notification-or-ajax-calling